# Iterative Approach with Gradient Descent - Linear Regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, supervised-learning

I have this model for scoring different schools:
[image]

And it is asked to me to describe an iterative approach to solve the problem.

Could it be a good way to answer to describe the polynomial regression with multiple variables ? 
Formalizing we have a dataset D with m samples.
I could define the error function J(theta) and find the parameters that minimizes the error function with the help of the gradient descent algorithm.

Could it be an iterative approach to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polynomial regression is considered to be a special case of a  multiple linear regression, and as such can be fitted with the gradient descent.

Gradient descent is an **iterative** optimization technique, and therefore if you minimize a cost function with gradient descent than the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Just one more thing , could it be a good way to have a better view of the function to initialize two new features x4 and x5 where x4 = x1*x2 and x5 = x3^2 ? In this way I should have the same number of features and parameters.